# Likelihood of one datapoint given $k$ models

Tags: bayesian, likelihood, posterior

**Introduction**

I'm currently facing a problem where I'm constraining a set of (physical) parameters $\theta_k$ with $k\in [1,2,...,K]$ via several independent datasets. One of those datasets, however, has *only one datapoint*, $Y$, which is a measurement of a physical variable. Given a realization of this datapoint, $y$, this puts a constraint on the parameters $\theta_k$ via a (known) function $f(\theta_k)$. The big question here is the distribution of $Y | \theta_1, \theta_2, ....,\theta_K$, i.e., the implied likelihood.

If I only had one parameter, $\theta_k$, then the probabilsitic model for $Y$ would be easy to derive in my case; it would be of the form

$Y \sim f(\theta_k) + \epsilon$,

with $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ with known $\sigma^2$ --- the error on the measurement of the realization $y$ of the variable $Y$, which I'm assuming is gaussian (which is a very good assumption in my case, by the way). As we all know, the likelihood of this model would be easily written as

$\displaystyle p(Y|\theta_k) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\exp\left(\frac{-(y-f(\theta_k))^2}{2\sigma^2}\right).\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \textrm{(1)}$

However, in my scenario, this datapoint has to simultaneously satisfy $k$ probabilistic models for the $\theta_k$ parameters simultaneously, as explained in the first paragraph: it simultaneously constrains the $\theta_k$ parameters.

**My approach**

I've comed up with many approaches to the problem, but the one that seems to be the most sound is the following. Our aim is to obtain

$p(Y|\theta_1,\theta_2,...) = \frac{p(\theta_1,\theta_2,...|Y) p(Y)}{p(\theta_1,\theta_2,...)},\ \ \ \ \ (2)$

where the right-hand side follows by Bayes Theorem. It turns out that $\theta_1, \theta_2,...$ are independent. This implies that $p(\theta_1,\theta_2,...)=\Pi_{k=1}^K p(\theta_k)$ and that $p(\theta_1,\theta_2,...|Y) = \Pi_{k=1}^K p(\theta_k|Y)$. Replacing this in (2) gives:

$p(Y|\theta_1,\theta_2,...) = p(Y)\frac{\Pi_{k=1}^K p(\theta_k|Y)}{\Pi_{k=1}^K p(\theta_k)}.\ \ \ \ \ (3)$

Now, from Bayes theorem, it follows that $p(\theta_k|Y) = p(Y|\theta_k)p(\theta_k)/p(Y)$. Replacing this in (3) we get:

$p(Y|\theta_1,\theta_2,...) = p(Y)\frac{\Pi_{k=1}^K p(Y|\theta_k)p(\theta_k)/p(Y)}{\Pi_{k=1}^K p(\theta_k)} = \left[p(Y)\right]^{1-K} \Pi_{k=1}^K p(Y|\theta_k),\ \ \ \ (5)$

where $p(Y|\theta_k)$ is given by equation (1) above.

**The question**

Does this sound as good as it does to me? What I see is that this is equivalent to a multiplication of the likelihoods of the "individual" likelihoods (the ones in equation (1)), but which are "penalized" by the $\left[p(Y)\right]^{1-K}$ term, which I suppose enters because we are not using $K$ datapoints (which would be what it would be implied if this term didn't exist) but, rather, our $k$ functions are being constrained by this one datapoint. However, I have never seen a likelihood like the one implied in equation (5); however, I wouldn't be surprised it exists somewhere in the literature. Pointers to similar cases would be well received as well!

Comment: How to define "independent datasets"? (1) =  $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}$

Comment: Hey @a_statistician; sorry, can you elaborate on your question?

Comment: 1. I do not know how the datasets can be independent, if independent means statistical independent. 2. in your first paragraph, $f(\theta_k)=y$ so, (1) = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}$.

Comment: 1. For the purposes of this question, we can think of $Y$ as being the only datapoint. 2. My bad on the first paragraph. Will change it.

Comment: Sorry: meant to say "$Y$ as being the only dataset".